# Modifying a Date Variable

Tags: sas-visual-analytics

I want to return the month from my date variable in SAS Visual Analytics. I did calculated item --> month('Date_Variable') and it returned numbers 1-12, but I want it to return the month name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need to calculate the month. Just use a format.

```
input(dateVariable, monname10.)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a new calculated item.

You can create a new duplicate of the date variable and change the format of that by right-clicking on the variable and changing the format.